# Regex match a character set within brackets containing other characters

Tags: regex

Given `foo bar monkey [foo bar monkey] foo bar monkey`, how would you match only the `bar` within the brackets?

`\[(bar)+\]` is as close as I can get it from an understanding and research perspective (brackets are matched, then we're selecting only the exact text within the brackets 1 or more times) however it matches nothing I want it to. `\[(.*)+\]` matches everything in brackets, including the brackets, but I can't seem to filter it to only `bar` regardless of what I try.

EDIT: I'm using a replace in directory function in a JetBrains IDE. I'm not sure what language they use for processing regex.

Comment: What tool / lang you are using?

Comment: Please indicate the language you are using. In any case, have you tried the regex `\[.*(bar).*\]` ?

Comment: Try [`\[[^ ]+ (bar) [^]]+]`](https://regex101.com/r/OiGogq/1)

Comment: @revo I'm doing a directory replace in a JetBrains IDE. I'm not sure what language they use for this.

Comment: Is unbalanced brackets existence probable?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't that the IDE is not using perl for the regex. It think it's javascript.

Comment: @revo If you mean something along the lines of `[ foo bar [ foo bar ]]` or `[ foo bar ] [ foo bar ]`, then no. I'll be able to take care of those on a case by case basis.

Comment: Check this `bar(?=[^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*\])`

Comment: And if you try [`\[[^ ]+ (bar) [^\]]+\]`](https://regex101.com/r/gVVt5e/1) with the escaped closing bracket?

Comment: @revo That works, but I can't figure out how. Please post an answer so I can mark it so. I simplified my answer to post on stackoverflow and assumed, incorrectly, apparently, that I'd be able to change the answer to fit my situation. Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/gVVt5e/2) to see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `\[[^\[\]]*(bar)[^\[\]]*\]` because capture groups are friendly.

Comment: This `text within the brackets 1 or more times)` is unclear. If you're saying you want to match all the bar's separately inside brackets like `[foo bar bar baz bar bar]` then a lookahead is needed. However, if not, these days, misinformed programmers think that they only want to match the subtext only as an _entire match_. This is utterly absurd, and why they make capture groups. If there is a scenario where you have more than one bar per paired bracket, it is wiser to capture the entire content's of the brackets, then run a global find on that.

Comment: I'm not sure if jetbrain uses Java regex flavor fully but if it does test this: `(?<=bar\([^(\\]{0,9999}(\\.[^(\\]{0,9999}){0,9999})chipmunk` it doesn't work in regex101.com though and please don't forget to ask for your real world issue next time you are going to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any `bar` within brackets (by knowing that unbalanced brackets are not likely to happen) you can use below regex:

```
bar(?=[^\]\[\\]*(?:\\.[^\]\[\\]*)*\])
```

**RegEx breakdown**:

```
bar     # Match `bar`
(?=     # Starting a positive lookahead, works as If condition
    [^\]\[\\]*  # If without matching `]` or `[` or `\`
    (?: # Start of non-capturing group #1
        \\.[^\]\[\\]* # Repeat last pattern in addition to matching escaped chars
    )*  # Many times, end of NCG #1
    \]  # When it ends to `]`
)       # End of lookahead
```

Running this over a string like this:

```
foo bar monkey [foo bar monkey bar foo] foo bar monkey [foo bar monkey bar foo]
```

will match all `bar`s within brackets. You may want to enclose it with `\b` to ensure matching `bar` words only: `\bbar\b`.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1zjzh/2)

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains' IDEs are written in Java 1.4 (which includes Java 1.4's regex engine). There are multiple ways you can accomplish what you're trying to do, but likely the easiest method is to not use capturing groups. Java supports variable length lookbehinds so long as you don't use the `+` or `*` quantifiers. As a *replacement* for these unsupported quantifiers, you can use something like `{0,1000}` to replace `*` and `{1,1000}` to replace `+`.

```
(?<=\[[^]]{0,1000})bar
```

- `(?<=\[[^]]{0,1000})` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches the following

  - `\[` Matches `[` literally
  - `[^]]{0,1000}` Match any character except `]` between 0 and 1000 times
- `bar` Match this literally

Running this regex yields the following results for me (using PHPStorm as a test)

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work when `bar` is not the middle word or if there are any more than 1 word before `bar` or if there are no words after bar, etc. It just matches the second word inside of the brackets.

Comment: @forrestmid are you looking to always match `bar`?

Comment: Yes. Only bar, only while in brackets.

Comment: @forrestmid please see edits. I changed regex. This should work for you. One last question though, do you want to match `bar` if it's part of another word such as `bartender`?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get along with

```
\[(?:(?!]).)*?bar
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/x6i2JE/2).

---

That is

```
\[         # match [
(?:        # non-capturing group
    (?!]). # neg. lookahead forbidding ]
)*?        # as few as possible
bar        # match bar
```

To *capture* `bar`, you could use

```
\[(?:(?!]).)*?(bar)
```

And use the first group.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
.*\[[^]]*?(bar)[^[]*?\].*
```

Which should capture `bar` as long as it is inside of some brackets. The `[^]]*?` / `[^[]*?` on each side of the `(bar)` are needed to consume the other things that are inside the brackets with the `bar`.

Note that this will not properly handle nested brackets, and will only find one `bar`, along with probably many other restrictions.

Comment: `monkey [foo ] bar [monkey] foo bar monkey` will match it too

Comment: I have found `(?<=\[[^\]]*)(bar)`

Comment: Variable-length lookbehinds aren't supported among most regex engines. @Leyffda

Comment: (revo : I didnt know I'm using js :/) @lxop You need to escape the first closing hook.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out. It works fine.

```
\[\w*\s(bar)\s\w+\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/FylOMj/1

Comment: Doesn't work in Java 1.4. ctwheels clarified the version JetBrains uses, however it does work in php.