# Regex match a string within 2 different strings containing other characters

Tags: regex, jetbrains-ide

Given `bar(alvin the chipmunk dude)` and `chipmunk(alvin the chipmunk dude)`, how would you match the word "chipmunk" only on the "bar" function?

Another question I just asked, but without the needed complexity I was looking for, is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890297/regex-match-a-character-set-within-brackets-containing-other-characters). I do not believe this is a duplicate given the answer to the question from @revo. That answer does answer the other question however I see no way to adapt it to ensure the match is contained within two different strings ("bar(" and ")").

`chipmunk(?=[^\)\(\\]*(?:\\.[^\)\(\\]*)*\))` (courtesy of @revo) matches "chipmunk" inside of the parentheses, but I want to constrain it to only to to being within "bar(" and ")".

[Test here.](https://regex101.com/r/gVVt5e/4)

Using JetBrains IDE which uses Java.

Comment: [Capture group 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969620/3103891) with [`(?:bar.*)(chipmunk)`](https://regex101.com/r/gVVt5e/5)

Comment: Yes, something like `(?<=bar\([^()]{0,1000})chipmunk` will most probably be enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890297/regex-match-a-character-set-within-brackets-containing-other-characters - very similar to your other question. I would suggest you try learning a little more about regex and how to use it. Play around with online regex IDEs and read Java's regex documentation

Comment: Actually, it is not quite clear what exactly you need. And in the previous post, you have all the hints to answer this question. Perhaps, you may also want to use `bar\([^()]*chipmunk[^()]*\)` here.

Comment: `"chipmunk" only on the "bar" function` Whoa, you need a language parser, not a regex. What language does the _function_ come from ? Language's can hide things in comments, string literals, all sorts of places...., not to mention balanced syntax..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That first answer works. Please post an answer so I can award credit. Part of my issue is my lack of regex knowledge. I spent about two hours prior to posting my first question and am excited to have learned so much however this lookback functionality in java is much more confusing than the JS regex I was playing with in the online editors.

Comment: @sln I was simplifying my question for SO. In reality the function is much more complicated and is syntactically correct. This is just a string for the sake of regex.

Comment: `I was simplifying my question for SO. In reality the function is much more complicated and is syntactically correct. This is just a string for the sake of regex` What I said in my comment went right over your head ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a Java regex library, you may leverage the [constrained-width lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) feature:

> Java accepts quantifiers within lookbehind, as long as the length of the matching strings falls within a pre-determined range. For instance, `(?<=cats?)` is valid because it can only match strings of three or four characters. Likewise, `(?<=A{1,10})` is valid.

You may use

```
(?<=bar\([^()]{0,1000})chipmunk
```

It matches any `chipmunk` string that is immediately preceded with `bar(` followed with 0 to 1000 chars other than `(` and `)`.

You may [test it at RegexPlanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyykfrgnr).